# Mariadb syntax error on Declare statement

Tags: mariadb, declare

I am creating a MariaDB stored procedure in phpmyAdmin and I keep getting a syntax error.

I have tried appending an @ symbol for the variable but I am still getting the error.

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
DECLARE @cNAME = VARCHAR(100);
SET @cNAME = "TEST";
SELECT * from tblUser where UserName = cNAME;
```

I expect that my stored procedure would get saved but it doesn't because of the syntax error.

Comment: `DECLARE @cNAME = VARCHAR(100);` - remove `=`

Comment: Okay, I just did that @LukaszSzozda, but now the syntax error is in the Select Statement.  I tried saving the stored procedure with only the SET statement and it saved.  But when I added the Select statement, i get the syntax error.

In addition, if the Select statement is the only one inside (changed to Select * from tblUser), it works.

But when both lines are included, even when the variable is not used in the Select statement, I get an error.  I am scratching my head.